# How do I run ng test and then ng build after tests pass in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-cli, karma-jasmine

I have an Angular 4 application that I'm setting up a build pipeline for. What I would like to do is have the pipeline run `ng test` and then once the tests pass then run `ng build`

Does anyone have an example of how I can do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

inside your package.json you can create a custom script.

```
"scripts": {
"build": "ng build",
"test": "ng test --single-run",
"ci": "npm run test && npm run build"
},
```

then just run

```
npm run ci
```

Comment: This is not running!! I'm using Angular6 and `--single-run` did not stop the tests. I have also tried `--watch=false` still same issue. Any updates on this one ?

Comment: maybe `--no-watch`?

Answer (score 31):

To add to the other answers: As of Angular 6 `--single-run` no longer works, but you should use this instead:

```
--watch=false
```

It is described [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/test):

> Tests will execute after a build is executed via Karma, and it will
>   automatically watch your files for changes. You can run tests a single
>   time via --watch=false.

So now you need to do:

```
ng test --watch=false && ng build
```

Answer (score 5):

`ng test --single-run && ng build`

Explanation:

- Firstly make sure to run ng test as single run, otherwise it'll never terminate: `ng test --single-run`.
- Then use double ampersand `&&` to indicate that the next command should only run on successful exit status.
- Then `ng build`.

This should work for both Windows and Linux systems...

Answer (score 1):

We created a "test-headless" script in our package.json file:

```
"test-headless": "ng test --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadless"
```

Our build pipeline runs `npm run test-headless` to run the tests in a headless browser, then ends the test after a single run.  We have a second step to run `ng build --configuration production` but you can also add a script in the package.json like:

`"ci": npm run test-headless && ng build --configuration production` then run `npm run ci` in your build pipeline.